# Add custom link to the chartJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am trying to add custom link to the chartJS chart as shown in image. Any suggestion is welcome..

Thanks all in advance..

[image]

Comment: This should be straightforward with an absolutely positioned element. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @timclutton I solved that.. I will be posting the solution soon. Thanks